# Selenium: Is it a good practice to kill and reopen browser after every test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide

I have a test suite as follows

Filename: LoginTest.java

```
@Test(description = "send invalid username")
void loginWithIncorrectUsername(){}

@Test(description = "send invalid password")
void loginWithIncorrectPassword(){}

@Test(description = "send valid credentials")
void loginWithCorrectCredentials(){}
```

Should I create one browser and run all the above test cases or I should quit the browser and reopen it for every single test case?

I am trying with reopening the browser

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the browser every time might use a lot of time, so reusing the session would be the better solution.

Althought, you might mind if the website recogises you (cookies), means you'll need to clear the cookies after a test case. For that, have a look at the offical documentation.